# Typescript: How to write the response in browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, steam-web-api

Similar to Response.Write() is their any equivalent syntax in type script

I'm calling the web api, from typescript which returns me the httpResponse message with content as file attachment, i jsut want to open that attachment file in browser through typescript

```
Public DownloadFile()
{
      var content = //Web API result        
      //Neeed to render this above content in browser      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write):

```
document.write("<h1>result 1</h1>");
document.write("<h1>result 2</h1>");
```

If you want to get the result out in the DOM on a page, then do something like this if you are using jquery:

```
$(document.body).text(‘Result 1’);
```

If you have multiple lines of results:

```
$('<p>').text('result 1').appendTo($(document.body));
$('<p>').text('result 2').appendTo($(document.body));
```

That could be a method like:

```
write(element: JQuery, text: string[]) {
            text.forEach(v => {
                $('<p>').text(v).appendTo(element);
            });
        }
```

And you can use it like: `this.write($('body'), ['result 1', 'result 2']);`

If not using jquery, then write a method like:

```
write(element: HTMLElement, text: string[]) {
            text.forEach(v => {
              document.body.innerHTML += v + '<br>';
            });
        }
```

And call it like: `this.write(document.body, ['result 1', 'result 2']);`

If you just want to see the result in a console, you can write `console.log(’result 1’, ’result 2’)`. You can see the result in a console like in Google Chrome Developer by pressing F12.